# Error codes when trying to manually backup iPod

Tags: backup, file-transfer, ipod

I'm attempting to backup all of the music from my 80GB iPod Classic to my Windows Vista computer. My old computer (originally linked to this iPod with a backed up copy of all music) died on me, so iTunes won't transfer music from my iPod to any other computer now. So I have to either use a 3rd party transfer software or transfer the music from the iPod's file system. Attempting a backup either of these ways results in errors that prevent the computer from transferring 95% of the music. The 3rd party software offers no information about the error, but copy/pasting from the iPod file system to the PC returns the following errors:

error code 0x80070022 (first error message) error code 0x80070057 (subsequent error messages for 95% of music files attempting to be copied)

If I try transferring through the iPod's file system on my Macbook Pro, I get error code -36.

I've tried restarting both the PC and iPod, and I've also tried the transfer in safe mode and copy-pasting files instead of just dragging a whole folder from ipod to computer. All attempts eventually have the same resulting error messages. I've even tried to transfer files onto a Linux machine to cover all bases. Most of the 12,000 songs on the iPod were ripped long ago from CDs I own. I've also painstakingly rated every one of these songs. I'm very worried that one day my iPod will crap out on me and the ratings will be gone forever and I'll have to spend tons of time reripping those CDs again. I've also googled this problem and have found little help.

Other details - this iPod was originally set up on a WinXP PC. Additionally, I should note that I have no problems connecting to iTunes or playing any of the music files. These errors are only preventing me from copying music files to my PC or Mac.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: I assume you have tried to link the iPod to this computer in order to back it up ( not clear in your description of the problem ).

Comment: @Ramhound - Yes, I've tried linking the iPod to the computer. iTunes just wants to sync the iPod with the music library on my computer (which is empty). Basically, it would end up replacing all my songs with nothing.